# Accessing a target computer that has VPN connection via SSH within private network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, private-network

I have a fairly standard private network setup with two PC's connected to a router:

```
Router
| |
| -> PC1
|
->PC2
```

When I am connecting from PC1 to PC2 via SSH using 192.168.. IP address, everything works just fine. However, I want to enable a VPN connection on PC2 (and PC2 only), and still have ability to connect to it within my private network. But, when I enable VPN connection on PC2, I can't connect to it from PC1 using 192.168.. IP address, even if ifconfig on PC2 shows that local network still has flags <UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>

Is there a way in this setup to connect to PC2 from within my private network using SSH? I know I am repeating myself here, but I just want to be clear: I don't need to SSH to my PC from outside network, that would've been open and shut case of port forwarding.

Both pc's run Debian based distros (PC1 is Ubuntu, PC2 is Raspbian)

I tried to find solutions here on SO and in general, but it seems most people almost exclusively have problems with setups that look like this:

```
PC1 ----> (Internet) ---> Router ---> PC2
```

And this setup doesn't really looks like mine. Plus I don't really want to mess with port forwarding until I am convinced that it is the only option.

PC2 netstat output:

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.189.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.189.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

ifconfig *without* VPN:

```
$ ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether -  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1042  bytes 156052 (152.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1042  bytes 156052 (152.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.189.174  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.189.255
        ether -  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26871875  bytes 39045623151 (36.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9704634  bytes 1330790356 (1.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ifconfig with VPN enabled:

```
$ ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1034  bytes 154982 (151.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1034  bytes 154982 (151.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nordlynx: flags=81<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.5.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.5.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets bytes 
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets bytes 
        TX errors 4  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.189.174  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.189.255
        ether txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets bytes 
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets bytes 
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: How is nordlynx setup?  I use a docker version and you can [whitelist local networks](https://github.com/bubuntux/nordlynx#:~:text=of%20default%20routes.-,ALLOWED_IPS,-0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: @BlindSpots, I use cli application provided by nordvpn on their website. Using docker is a bit advanced for me, I am not familiar with it yet

Comment: `nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16` – To add a rule to whitelist a specified subnet
`nordvpn whitelist remove subnet 192.168.0.0/16`  – To remove the same rule

Comment: @BlindSpots, thank you, that has resolved my issue! Can you point me towards some source to read/watch to understand the idea behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user [Blind Spots](https://superuser.com/users/1007040/blind-spots):

> nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16 – To add a rule to
> whitelist a specified subnet nordvpn whitelist remove subnet
> 192.168.0.0/16 – To remove the same rule